# cierre automatico en mi app

Tags: java, android-studio, app

Hola tengo un problema con una app que estoy diseñando. El problema se trata que al momento de ejecutar la app funciona bien pero al momento de pasar a la siguiente pantalla se cierra la aplicación arrojando un error,
lo que debe de hacer la aplicación es que al momento de elegir si se quiere registrar o ingresar debe  mandarle a otra pantalla solicitando los datos del usuario, pero al momento de presionar alguno de los botones se cierra la aplicación en automático. Adjunto el código.

Pantalla inicial en donde se ejecuta la aplicacion

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
            android:translationY="150dp"
            android:translationX="-40dp"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:textColor="#232425"
            android:text="Beer Pong" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Iniciar Sesion"
            android:onClick="login"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/cardview_dark_background"
            android:translationY="250dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/singup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Registrate"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/cardview_dark_background"
            android:translationY="300dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Codigo de la pantalla inicial en donde se debe de ejecutar el codigo para redirigir a la otra pantalla del login

```
package com.example.beerpong;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        Button btn0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.singup);
    }
    public void login(View view){
        Intent intet = new Intent(this, Login.class);
        startActivity(intet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Desclaraste en el manisfiesto la actividad hija. Como lo dice aqui  ( https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity?hl=es-419 )[ como iniciar otra actividad ] es obligatorio declararl

Comment: Al revés, @DanielBriceño! Primero [nombre] y luego todo junto el (enlace)

Comment: Desclaraste en el manisfiesto la actividad hija. Como lo dice aqui [¿Como iniciar otra actividad?](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/…) es obligatorio declararlo.

Comment: lo hice pero aun asi se cierra de todos modos

Comment: Y como es el código java de la otra actividad y El xml.

Comment: Te dejo este ejemplo: [EjemploDeSegundaActividad](https://github.com/dabl03/Classic-juego/raw/main/ExampleDeActividadesEnAndroid/EjemploDeSegundaActividad.rar) . La explicación es: Te dejo dos archivo, uno contiene el codigo fuente y el otro contiene el apk. –

Comment: Para hacer esta app. No use jetpack porque las unica vez que intenté usarlo mi android no pudo leer el paquete apk.\n -Use relativelayout para posicionar todos los objecto.\n -Declare en el manisfiesto la segunda actividad.\n -Agregé un boton en la segunda actividad que es para regresar a la actividad principal.\n - Si precionas el boton verde la app se cerrará. Porque en el manisfesto puse el permiso necesario dentro de comentario porque asi demuestro los sintomas que tu describes.\n No pongo esto como respuesta porque no estoy muy seguro de que si ver este codigo te ayude.